# Closest Facility - time-based cost attribute issue?

Tags: arcmap

WHat I wish to acheive: To find the best route from point A to B and A to C.

What I have done so far: I have a shape with the road network in an area that I used "New network dataset" on. I also have point data for "Facility" and "incident".

WHat the issue is: Whenever I try to run "find closest facility" I get an error stating the following: "ERROR 030098 The network dataset must have at least one time-based and one distance-based cost attribute.".

I do have a distance based cost attribute but not sure how to go about getting the time based cost attribute? Is there a way around the time based attribute? All I want is the best route and the distance, time is irrelevant for me.